# Printing dictionary contents using format method

Tags: python, dictionary, string-formatting

I just started learning python and tried printing the dictionary contents using format function. I gained some insight while reading https://www.python-course.eu/python3_formatted_output.php

Question 1 : The double * operator is used performing exponential calculations, how it behaves with the dictionaries?

Question 2 : For this block of code I am getting `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. I must have misinterpreted something.

```
students = {100 : "Udit", 101 : "Rohan", 102 : "Akash", 103 : "Rajul"}
for student in students :
    format_string = str(student) + ": {" + str(student) + "}"
    print(format_string)
    print(format_string.format(**students))
```

Comment: First, don't ask multiple questions in a single question if you want a good answer. Create separate questions (if they're related add links between them, and make sure your questions are clear enough that nobody will think they're the same question).

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: Anyway: (1) It's not an operator here, it's [keyword splatting, part of the function call syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists0. They're no more the same thing than the parentheses around the tuple `(1, 2)`, the parentheses around the subexpression in `2 * (3 + 4)`, and the parentheses in the function call `spam(42)` are the same thing.

Comment: As a side note, building format strings dynamically like this is usually not a good idea. What you're trying to do here can be done a lot more simply without it. Just `for num, student in students.items(): print(f'{num}: {student}')` is a lot more readable.

Comment: And (2): the problem is that `for student in students:` is looping over the _keys_ of your dictionary. So, that format string you build is `"100: {100}"`. That means you're trying to insert positional argument #100 out of 0.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert for the solution and I will make sure I won't repeat the same mistake while asking the questions.

Comment: Thanks @StephenRauch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You iterate like this:

```
for student in students :
```

Since `students` is a dict, this iterates over the keys, which are numbers, like `100`, which means end up building a format string like this:

```
'100: {100}'
```

And then, when you call `format` on that, the `100` is asking for positional argument #100. But you only passed 0. So you get an `IndexError`.

You can only usefully use the `format(**students)` syntax when the dict keys are valid string format keys.

---

Meanwhile, I don't know who's been spreading the idea that `format(**d)` is a great idea. If you want to format using only a dict or other mapping, that's what [`format_map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map) was added for, back in 3.2:

```
print(format_string.format_map(students))
```

One advantage is that when you do something wrong, you get a more useful error message:

```
ValueError: Format string contains positional fields
```

When you see that, you can print out the format string itself and see that `{100}`, and, yep, that's a positional field. Much less debugging needed.

More importantly, it's simpler to read and understand without the keyword splatting. And it's even more efficient (not as much so in 3.6 as in 3.2, but `format` still has to build a new dict copy, while `format_map` can use whatever mapping you give it as-is).

---

Finally, building a format string dynamically like this is rarely a good idea. A much simpler way to print what you're trying to print is:

```
for num, student in students.items():
    print(f'{num}: {student}')
```

Or, if you're not using 3.6, or just want to use `format` or `format_map` explicitly instead of f-strings, same idea.